# How to get the current upload percentage using jquery + nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, file-upload, express, progress-bar

I m trying to upload a file using jquery, ajax, express and nodejs. Here I want to show the progress of upload. May be there is a plugin or something else. No need to post that answers. I want to study the technique behind that. So please help me if you know how to handle this. I have an ajax call to upload the file.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/controller/action',
    //remaining parameters 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this code. I think it will help you. Also you can use this plugin [JQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

```
this.uploadFile =  function(index) {
    //baseClass == this
    var file = baseClass.allFiles[index];

    //Creating instance of FormData
    var data = new FormData();
    //Adding file
    data.append('uploadFile', file.file);

    //Sending it with ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            var message = file.element.find('td.message');
            if(response.status == 'ok') {
                message.html(response.text);
                file.element.find('button.uploadButton').remove();
            }
            else {
                message.html(response.errors);
            }
        },
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

            if ( xhr.upload ) {
                console.log('xhr upload');

                xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                    file.progressDone = e.position || e.loaded;
                    file.progressTotal = e.totalSize || e.total;
                    //updating downloading progress for the file
                    baseClass.updateFileProgress(index, file.progressDone, file.progressTotal, file.element);

                    //updating total progress
                    baseClass.totalProgressUpdated();
                };
            }

            return xhr;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use Multer to upload your file:
[Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: Currently Multer doesn't offer progress tracking: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/243